# Calculating lengths of conjugated diameters of an ellipse

Tags: geometry

Let be $ E$ an ellipse with the longer semi axis $a$ and shorter semi axis $b$

The conjugated diameters $d_1 $ given by $y=Ax$    and $d_2$ given by y=$Bx $

And the lengths beeing $ |d_1|= l_1 $ and $ |d_2 | = l_2 $

Now..how can I calculate $$l_1^2 + l_2^2 $$

in dependency of $A$ ( a and b) ?

So I guess I first have to figure out how $A$ and $B$ look exactly..but here I also stumble and would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ellipse vector equation is

$ p(t) = v_1 \cos(t) + v_2 \sin(t) $

Shifting $t$ and substituting $ t + \tau $ in its place gives

$ p(t) = \bigg(v_1 \cos(\tau) + v_2 \sin(\tau) \bigg) \cos(t) + \bigg(- v_1 \sin(\tau) + v_2 \cos(\tau) \bigg) \sin(t) $

which is of the form

$ p(t) = w_1(\tau) \cos(t) + w_2(\tau) \sin(t ) $

where

$ w_1(\tau) = v_1 \cos(\tau) + v_2 \sin(\tau) $

$ w_2(\tau) = - v_1 \sin(\tau) + v_2 \cos(\tau) $

The $w$'s are the conjugate semi-axes.  It is straight forward to check that

$ \| w_1 \|^2 + \| w_2 \|^2 = \| v_1 \|^2 + \| v_2 \|^2 $

Hence,

$ l_1^2 + l_2^2 = a^2 + b^2 $